# Finding the employee of the same last two digits Employee ID in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a below scenario in Hive

```
Emp ID | Employee name | Emp salary    
112    | Prakash       | 33333       
212    | Aakash        | 5567
322    | Kishore       | 565
3242   | hhjh          | 76676
4325   | chhh          | 565
422    | Ramesh        | 34555
```

I want to find out the Employee name whose last two digits of employee ID are same:

eg.  Prakash and Aakash have the same last digit of the employee ID & Kishore and Ramesh also have the same.

Output :

```
112    | Prakash            
212    | Aakash       
322    | Kishore  
422    | Ramesh
```

Comment: Add the requested result (in a table format)

Comment: Edited .Thanks to Patrick !

Comment: **(1)** select the text and press Ctrl-k in order to format code.  **(2)** You still haven't supplied the requested result (in a table format)

Comment: Please add it to your original post and not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
select  `Emp ID`
       ,`Employee name`

from   (select  `Emp ID`
               ,`Employee name`
               ,count(*) over (partition by `Emp ID` % 100) as cnt

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   cnt > 1
;
```

---

```
+--------+---------------+
| emp id | employee name |
+--------+---------------+
|    212 | Aakash        |
|    112 | Prakash       |
|    422 | Ramesh        |
|    322 | Kishore       |
+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you pls explain

Comment: Do you undetstand the `count` function?

Comment: Here is my understanding:  slicing the data by the last two digits and  counting the slices  with each Emp ID , Employee name .Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: It's all because of this count(*) function. thanks for your help!